# I am having trouble figuring out why my code will not print the calculation for the GPA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
using System;

namespace gpa
{
    class gpa
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            double credit = 0;
            double totalCreditHours = 0;

        char grade = ' ';
        double gradePoints = 0;
        double totalGradePoints = 0;

        int counter = 0;
        double gpa = 0;

        do 
        {
            Console.Write("Enter letter grade for class #{0} \n(use A, B, C, or D. Type 0 after all classes entered.): ", counter += 1);
            char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userInput == '0')
            {
                break;
            }

            else 
            {
                grade = userInput;
                Console.Write("Enter your credit hours: ");
                credit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (grade)
                {
                    case 'A': gradePoints = 4;
                        break;
                    case 'B': gradePoints = 3;
                        break;
                    case 'C': gradePoints = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'D': gradePoints = 1;
                        break;

                }

                totalGradePoints = totalGradePoints + (credit * gradePoints);
                totalCreditHours = totalCreditHours + credit;

            } 

        } while (grade != 0);

            gpa = CalculateGPA(totalGradePoints, totalCreditHours);
            Console.Write("Your GPA is ", gpa);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static double CalculateGPA(double totalGradePoints, double totalCreditHours)
        {
            return (totalGradePoints / totalCreditHours);

        }
    }
}
```

----this last part is what i think is wrong, but i am not sure how to fix it. It will not output the actual calculated gpa

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "It will not output the actual calculated gpa"? Is your calculation wrong, does the console not show anything or are you never reaching that block of code?

Comment: Youre missing {0} -> "Your GPA is {0}"

Comment: Is there a way to set a default so that if the user inputs a letter other than A B C D or F that itll give an error message??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this line instead -

```
Console.Write("Your GPA is " + gpa);
```

Or

```
Console.Write("Your GPA is {0}" ,gpa);
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a default so that if the user inputs a letter other than A B C D or F that itll give an error message??